# SASS/SCSS @mixin for vendor prefixes without using a map

Tags: sass

I'm pretty new too SASS/SCSS but essentially. I have a mixin for vendor prefixing things:

```
@mixin prefix($props) {
  @each $prop, $val in $props {
    @each $prefix in (ms, moz, ms) {
      #{'-' + $prefix + '-' + $prop}: $val;
    }
    #{$prop}: $val;
  }
}
```

This works except I have to do something like:

```
.myclass {
  @include prefix((
    transform: translateY(180deg),
    perspective: 1000px
  ))
}
```

This feels unnecessarily bulky, surely there must be a way where I can write it **like**:

```
.myclass {
  @include prefix {
    transform: translateY(180deg);
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
}
```

or even:

```
.myclass {
  @include prefix(
    transform: translateY(180deg),
    perspective: 1000px
  )
}
```

I know SASS/SCSS has `...` which can be used to a list of arguments. Is there something similar which returns a map?

Comment: @cimmanon this isn't a duplicate, that doesn't answer my question at all. I'm asking how to apply the *vendor prefixes*. Did you actually read the question or just the title and just close it? I'm perfectly aware of `@content` but in my case I don't see how it can be used

Comment: Did you read the answer before insisting its not a duplicate?  The way you've presented your "desired way of writing it", you require a mixin that uses `@content`.  From the accepted answer: "No, `@content` is not a variable. You cannot set a default value to it. You cannot manipulate or examine it."  I don't know how you could possibly read that and think, "well maybe there's a way I can add prefixes to that".

Comment: @cimmanon As I said, "I'm pretty new too SASS/SCSS". If there's no solution then how's it a duplicate? Future visitors will be directed to a page without an answer. and that's *if* `@content` is the *only possible* solution.

Comment: Future visitors won't be coming to this page for answers, they'll be coming to one of the hundreds of other "how do I do prefixes" questions that have existed long before mappings were added to the language.  The way you want to write your code can't be done.

Comment: @cimmanon there, `@content is not a variable. You cannot set a default value to it. You cannot manipulate or examine it.` isn't the answer, it's `The way you want to write your code can't be done`. "hundreds of others"? The duplicate may contain information related to this question but it's in *no* way a duplicate. Many SO questions contain related information, that's why the "Linked" section is there in the sidebars. Duplicates are the *same* question. That's not the same question

Comment: First off, stop abusing the code tags for quotes. Second, the way you want to write cannot be done for reasons explained in the question I closed this as a duplicate of.  I am not interested in curating 2 questions that want to do the same thing (treat `@content` as a variable) when this behavior changes in a future version of Sass.  P.S. There are multiple reasons why none of the major prefix libraries do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Autoprefixer exists for a reason. I suggest you use that rather than trying to create some wonky mixin to achieve the same thing.